# jquery validation not working for this code

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Could anyone pleae figure out why this code is not working ? I can click submit button and go to next page without selecting anything. I want user to be allowed to go to next page only if the user selects any radio button. Thanks

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js'></script>

  <script>
  $.noConflict();
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").validate();
  });
  </script>

 <form method="post"  action="/action" id="form1" class="styled" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="name">1. Choose Category</label><br />
<select class="required" id="cat1" name="category">
                <option>select Category</option>

                    <option class="required" value="10">Cars</option>
                    <option class="required" value="8">House</option>
                    <option class="required" value="11">Mobiles</option>
                    <option class="required" value="3">Bus</option>
                    <option class="required" value="6">Services</option>
          </select>

        <input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Next Step"   class="btn-submit img-swap"  id="submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems that the validation plugin requires jQuery 1.6.4+ and you are using v1.6.1, other than that your code seems to be fine.

Comment: `I want user to be allowed to go to next page only if the user selects any radio button.` there are no radio buttons in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick view, your code seems to be fine but after a detailed view, the culprit is this html line :

```
<option>select Category</option>
```

... which also requires to have a(n) (empty) `value` attribute for the plugin to work properly, so it should look like :

```
<option value="">select Category</option>
```

... or much better :

```
<option selected="" value="" disabled="disabled">select Category</option>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cjfKt/)** using jQuery v1.6.4, as in my previous comment